# How to margin bottom without float?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of links for a menu and those links should be centered when the window size isn't big enough to hold them all in one line. So I made this CSS:

```
.aboutLevel2,
.centerLevel2 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
}
.centerLevel2 a {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 7px 10px 6px 15px;
  background: #595959;
  color: #fff;
}
```

And it centers the links fine, but `margin-bottom: 25px` doesn't work. How could I make the links have that kind of a margin when they have been centered because the window size isn't big enough to let them all stay in one line?

**Edit** http://jsfiddle.net/rvwzcjzq/

Comment: can you post a demo?

Comment: @Amit added a link to jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Margins won't work because you're using `float` and so the container that contains those elements won't have the expected height. There are 3 solutions: a) use padding instead of margin (not always possible) or b) add an empty clearing div after the floated elements, something like this: `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` or c) add `overflow:hidden;` to the container. You can read more about the issue you're discussing by Googling for *"clearing div after float"*

Edit: now that you've added a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvwzcjzq/7/), you can fix your problem like this:

```
.aboutLevel2, .centerLevel2 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.centerLevel2 a {
    margin-right: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding: 7px 10px 6px 15px;
    background: #595959;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix your problem with add `display: block;` to your links :

```
.centerLevel2 a {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 55px;
padding: 7px 10px 6px 15px;
background: #595959;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) property

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rvwzcjzq/2/)

```
.centerLevel2 a {
margin-right: 10px;
line-height: 35px;
padding: 7px 10px 6px 15px;
background: #595959;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `display:inline-block` to `.centerLevel2 > a` not for `.centerLevel2` like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvwzcjzq/4/)**

```
.centerLevel2 > a {
    margin: 0px 10px 55px 0;
    padding: 7px 10px 6px 15px;
    background: #595959;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
     display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `display: inline-block;` to anchor tag for giving margin.

```
.centerLevel2 a {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 55px;
    padding: 7px 10px 6px 15px;
    background: #595959;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Check [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvwzcjzq/5/)